# How to close the database connection in peewee from mysql explicitly

Tags: peewee

I create connect to db using the below function in **db/core.py**

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import peewee

proxy = peewee.proxy()    

@contextmanager
def get_database(distribution_type):
    if distribution_type == "local":
        yield peewee.MySQLDatabase("db_local", user="root", host="test-db", port="3306")
    else:
         yield peewee.MySQLDatabase("db_prod", user="root", host="prod_db", port="3306") 

class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = proxy
```

later I import this module to

**db/manager.py**

```
from core import get_database, proxy

class DistributionManager(object):
    def __init__(self, distribution_type="local"):
        super(DistributionManager, self).__init__()
        self._distribution_type = distribution_type
        self._initialize_database()

    def _initialize_database(self):
        with get_database(self._distribuition_type) as db:
            proxy.initialize(db)

    def create(self, source, dest):
        self._pw_model = DistributionModel.create(source=source, dest=dest)
```

so my question is how do I call `db.close()` explicitly when db is not public ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to call `proxy.close()`, which will dispatch the close() call to the database object.